# Implementing Touch Event on a custom object android

Tags: android

I am trying to write a simple program using Surface View. I have an Object called ball which is drawn on the Surface and keeps moving around. I want to enable the Touch Event on the Object. The objective is stop the ball moving for a few secs when I touch it. I am not sure how to go about adding setOnTouchListener to the Customer Object ball.

I was able to create a custom view on top of Surface View. But when I touch the ball which is the custom view its not responding to touch. I have implemented the OnTouchListener and also set the setOnTouchListener. I am pretty new so running into issues.

Answer (score 1):

Extend the View class. Check out the link below for custom components and touch events on a canvas.

[View.OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

[Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

[Some extra links for touch events and canvas drawables](https://www.google.com/search?q=Canvas%20drawable%20touch%20event)